# Grouping array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an already sorted array. Assuming my sorted array is

```
 [60 , 60 ,60, 56 , 56 ,45 , 33 , 12, 10]
```

I want to place this array in an object of this form using javascript

```
 {first : [60 ,60 ,60] , second : [56 ,56] , third : [33]}
```

Please any help will be appreciated. THanks

Comment: What about `12` and `10`? Please explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Please show us where you've gotten to so far :)

Comment: `{ first: arr.slice(0, 3), second: ... }`…?

Comment: i am trying to get the first second and third rank of the score. I want to know how many scores are in the first rank, second rank and third rank.

Comment: Then should `third` not be `45`?

Comment: I have no idea how exactly you're defining "rank" or how your input fits your desired output…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested approach with two loops, one for the wanted keys and one for the length of the array with the numbers.

```js
var numbers = [60, 60, 60, 56, 56, 45, 33, 12, 10],
    object = {},
    i = 0; j = 0,
    keys = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
    last = numbers[0];

while (i < keys.length) {
    object[keys[i]] = object[keys[i]] || [];
    while (j < numbers.length && numbers[j] === last) {
        object[keys[i]].push(numbers[j]);
        j++;
    }
    last = numbers[j];
    i++;
}

console.log(object);
```

A proposal with more compact style.

```js
function groupByTop(items, object) {
    var last = numbers[0]
        j = 0;

    return function (k) {
        object[k] = object[k] || [];
        while (j < items.length && items[j] === last) {
            object[k].push(items[j]);
            j++;
        }
        last = items[j];
    };
}

var numbers = [60, 60, 60, 56, 56, 45, 33, 12, 10],
    result = {};

['first', 'second', 'third'].forEach(groupByTop(numbers, result));

console.log(result);
```